# Access failed with cd and mput commands in shell script

Tags: shell, cp, mv

I have written a shell script to take mysql database backup and at the same time connecting to other server using lftp and transferring backup to other server

I am able to connect to other server using lftp but when i am using cp or mv or mput command to transfer the files it says "Access failed 550: " error

For cp commands it says "Unknown Command: cp"

Please help me if someone has faced such an issue and have solution to get it resolved.

Thanks,
Chetan Panchal

Answer (score 0):

To put a file on a server that you have connected to with lftp, you use the 'put' command, not cp or mv.  To get a file from the server you use 'get'.  To put multiple files at once, use 'mput' or to get multiple files at once use 'mget', although you will probably be prompted for each file that is uploaded/downloaded.

If you still get errors make sure you have permission to put files in the directory that you are in on the server.

Comment: for most ftp clients (there are many differences), the `-i` option toggles the interactive feature on mput/mget. If you get prompted like 'OK to copy file x', add `-i` to your cmd-line call to `ftp` and that should stop the prompting. Good luck to all.\